# Multiple slideable side-panels

Tags: css, slide

I'm trying to create **Multiple slideable side-panels**, hidden outside right side of the screen.

[Here the prototype](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/ax1dyvLq/10/) (*in which I transated them "**almost**" outside the right side for better understanding behaviour*).

Relevat part of code is:

```
.container {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:200px;
  height:100%;
  transform:translateX(150px);      /*Should be 170px to place outside view*/
}

.side-panel {
  display:flex;
}

.side-panel.open {
  transform:translateX(-170px);
}

.content {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  width:calc(100% - 34px);
  height:100%;
}
```

As you can see, there 3 side.panels, each one openable clicking on its yellow label (indicated ad 1, 2, 3). In semi-hidden area, you can see also contents of each pane, overlapped.

The goal should be that `.toggle` labels should be stacked like in the example, but theirs contents should fill the entire height of the container (is possible to see that when panels are closed to the right that contents in this situation are effectively overlapped thanks to their `position:absolute`, but when you open one of them, it will be limited to its direct flex container) in the same way you can see when they are closed.

Please, how to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking for refer below link. Thanks

added height to `.side-panel.open`

https://jsfiddle.net/wyn7b8rx/1/`88`

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately is not my desired behaviour... other labels should remain in their positions like my first example (only the contents should be maximized)...

Comment: but it will go under the 1st label content.. is that okay with you??

Comment: Yes, I added `padding-right` to my example to address this :-)

Comment: can you please upvote my answer if it helped you. thanks

Comment: As I said... it's not the solution that I'd need... I added padding to address issue you noted, but desired behaviour it was described in original question and above comment...